# Create Class object from variable value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to create an object of a class from a returned string but I am getting error `Class **test_report** not found`. My code:

```
public function display_report_builder($report_name = null)
{
    $column_listing = new $report_name;// gets the test_report
    return view('column_list')->with(['column_list_names' => $column_listing->columns]);    
}
```

Comment: So, do you really have this class? Does autoloader know about this class?

Comment: @JeffLambert test_report is child model class as below  
    
    `class test_report extends Reports{

     public function __construct(){
  
      $this->columns = $this->getColumns();
     }

    }`
I have added a `use App\reports\test_report;` to access model.
And function `display_report_builder($report_name = null)` is in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the better approach here. What you should do is to use a [Factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)):

```
class ReportFactory
{
    public static function create($report_name)
    {
        switch($report_name) {
            case 'test_report': return new TestReport();
            default: throw new Exception('report not found');
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call with `$column_listing = ReportFactory::create($report_name);`

Why? Because you avoid "magic variables" with unknown data; you can trace errors properly; you can use namespace; you can extend functionalities easily, and easily activate or deactivate objects (or reports in this case); you have a cleaner code, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

test if the class name (string) really is a valid class :

```
public function display_report_builder($report_name = null)
{
   $column_list_names = null;

   if (class_exists($report_name) && is_a($report_name, App\reports\test_report::class, true)) {
      $column_listing = new $report_name;
      $column_list_names = $column_listing->columns;
   }

   return view('column_list', compact('column_list_names'));    
}
```

> [is_a()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) : Checks if the given object is of this class or has this class
>   as one of its parents.

Comment: it still says class not found.

Comment: did you try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I am getting nothing in the array. the empty array I am getting. So, probably is not finding class 'test_report'

Comment: yes it worked for me.   Thank you for your help @yoeunes